# Union of two term matrix in R

Tags: r, tm, trigonometry

I have two document term matrix. I am unable to take union of these two matrices as matrix of two different length.

```
A <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray right leg arteries",
  "x-ray left shoulder",
  "x-ray leg arteries",
  "x-ray leg with 20km distance"
), stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray left leg arteries",
  "X-ray leg",
  "xray right leg",
  "X-ray right leg arteries"
), stringsAsFactors = F)


library(tm)

# A
doc_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(A$name))
control_list <- list(weighting=weightBin, removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE, tolower = TRUE)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc_corpus, control = control_list)
tf <- as.matrix(dtm)

# B
doc_corpus2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(B$name))
control_list2 <- list(weighting=weightBin, removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE, tolower = TRUE)
dtm2 <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc_corpus2, control = control_list)
tf2 <- as.matrix(dtm2)
```

**tf[1,]**

```
arteries      leg      ray    right     left shoulder     20km distance 
       1        1        1        1        0        0        0        0
```

**tf2[4,]**

```
arteries     left      leg      ray    right     xray 
       1        0        1        1        1        0
```

If I take sum of Multiplication of these two matrices, it return 3. It should be 4. To fix it,

```
sum(tf[1,][tf[1,]==1] * tf2[4,][tf2[4,]==1])
```

But it does not consider the terms while calculation. For example, compare `tf[1,]` and `tf2[1,]`

```
sum(tf[1,][tf[1,]==1] * tf2[1,][tf2[1,]==1])
```

It should be 3 but it returns to 4.

I am performing the above calculation to calculate cosine similarity (see the formula below).

```
similarity = (sum(tf[1,] * tf2[4,])) / ( sqrt(sum(tf2[4,] ^ 2)) * sqrt(    sum(tf[1,] ^ 2)))
```

Comment: I have solved it using bind_rows() function of dplyr.

library(dplyr)
x = bind_rows(tf[1,] , tf2[4,])
x = data.frame(x)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that is not only more straightforward, but also maintains the full sparsity of the objects.  For you to compute cosine similarity using the approach in the question, you are coercing a potentially very large document-term matrix into a dense matrix.  The method below avoids that.

```
library("quanteda")

corp1 <- corpus(A, text_field = "name")
corp2 <- corpus(B, text_field = "name")

# unnecessary but better for distiguishing documents
docnames(corp1) <- paste("A", seq_len(ndoc(corp1)), sep = ".")
docnames(corp2) <- paste("B", seq_len(ndoc(corp2)), sep = ".")
```

The the `rbind.dfm()` method will magically join them and match the features.  (Note: An equivalent way to do this would be using the `+` operator for merging corpus objects: `dtm2 <- dfm(corp1 + corp2)`.  Try it!)

```
dtm3 <- rbind(dfm(corp1), dfm(corp2))
dtm3
# Document-feature matrix of: 8 documents, 10 features (65% sparse).
# 8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
#      features
# docs  x-ray right leg arteries left shoulder with 20km distance xray
#   A.1     1     1   1        1    0        0    0    0        0    0
#   A.2     1     0   0        0    1        1    0    0        0    0
#   A.3     1     0   1        1    0        0    0    0        0    0
#   A.4     1     0   1        0    0        0    1    1        1    0
#   B.1     1     0   1        1    1        0    0    0        0    0
#   B.2     1     0   1        0    0        0    0    0        0    0
#   B.3     0     1   1        0    0        0    0    0        0    1
#   B.4     1     1   1        1    0        0    0    0        0    0
```

(Sparse) computation of the cosine similarity matrix as a `dist` class object is then:

```
textstat_simil(dtm3, method = "cosine")
#           A.1       A.2       A.3       A.4       B.1       B.2       B.3
# A.2 0.2886751                                                            
# A.3 0.8660254 0.3333333                                                  
# A.4 0.4472136 0.2581989 0.5163978                                        
# B.1 0.7500000 0.5773503 0.8660254 0.4472136                              
# B.2 0.7071068 0.4082483 0.8164966 0.6324555 0.7071068                    
# B.3 0.5773503 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.2581989 0.2886751 0.4082483          
# B.4 1.0000000 0.2886751 0.8660254 0.4472136 0.7500000 0.7071068 0.5773503
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Highly appreciated! Since my real corpus 'A' contains more than 5k documents and another corpus 'B' contains close to 2k documents, it would not be a good idea to calculate similarity of documents of corpus A within the corpus as my goal is to calculate similarity of rows of corpus A with corpus B. Do you think any way to do it  efficiently?

Comment: 5k documents should be fine, and the method outlined is very efficient. You could compare one document from A at a time however using the `selection` argument. See ?`textstat_simil`.

Comment: Thanks Ken. It's super fast as compared to my for loop solution. I am just struggling to get it - "compare one document from A at a time". Is it already in quanteda package? Or I need to wrap it in a loop?

Comment: I suggest you state exactly what you want from the comparison as an output (what format) and post a separate question to the [quanteda channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quanteda).

Comment: Sure Ken. Will do that. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `bind_rows()`

You can combine two `corpus` or two `dtm` with `c()`

as in the documentation:

> tm_combine: Combine several corpora into a single one, combine
>   multiple documents into a corpus, combine multiple term-document
>   matrices into a single one, or combine multiple term frequency vectors
>   into a single term-document matrix.
>
> ```
> #S3 method for class 'VCorpus' 
> c(..., recursive = FALSE)
> ##S3 method for class 'TextDocument' 
> c(..., recursive = FALSE)
> ##S3 method for class 'TermDocumentMatrix' 
> c(..., recursive = FALSE)
> ##S3 method for class 'term_frequency' 
> c(..., recursive = FALSE)
> ```

Using your dtm and dtm2:

```
dtm3 <- c(dtm, dtm2)
as.matrix(dtm3)

    Terms
Docs arteries leg ray right left shoulder 20km distance xray
   1        1   1   1     1    0        0    0        0    0
   2        0   0   1     0    1        1    0        0    0
   3        1   1   1     0    0        0    0        0    0
   4        0   1   1     0    0        0    1        1    0
   1        1   1   1     0    1        0    0        0    0
   2        0   1   1     0    0        0    0        0    0
   3        0   1   0     1    0        0    0        0    1
   4        1   1   1     1    0        0    0        0    0
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I need to calculate cosine distance between each of the document of dtm with dtm2. After combining document term matrix, I am not able to calculate distance as number of documents in real is of unequal size and vary